# Bringing pot-grown aubergines into the house for winter -- is it worth it?

Tags: houseplants, vegetables

I've got a few aubergines growing in pots in the greenhouse, and they were a bit slow to get going this year despite a warm summer.  One* has a couple of fruit that are swelling up nicely but the others have only just flowered and I'm thinking ahead to the first frosts.  I've brought the best one into the house already, inside a south-ish facing window, but are the others likely to do anything indoors? They're not small pots so I've got limited space for them.

---

* Strangely, the one that's doing best is in a pot with no drainage and was waterlogged for a couple of weeks.

Comment: I haven't got the rep to suggest a tag synonym here but it seems like an obvious one (and it doesn't seem right to have a tag that doesn't match the question)

Comment: I would say: try it. I never succeeded to move a aubergine plants from outside to green house (but mine plants were not in a pot).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi a lot of people seem to have tried lifting them from the ground without much success, and I hope I'm in a better position than them.  The limited space for large pots indoors means I might have to leave some chillies outside if I bring the aubergines in, so if it's hopeless I don't want to waste the chillies (though my [Aji Limon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_drop_pepper) have all done rather well and I may have more than I can use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experiment was a failure in the end, though perhaps a promising one.  Two out of three survived the winter, but then died in the spring.  I think this was mainly because having been rather dormant and not needing much water they suddenly got going again just before I went away for a week, and dried out.  I may try again at some point, though this year's plants have never looked happy.